# Анализ отклонений в почтовом траффике с помощью Python

Tags: python, неопределённое-поведение

Меня заинтересовала задача по анализу отклонений в поведении пользователей при использовании электронной почты.
Одно почтовое сообщение содержит поля : ID сообщения, кому, куда, тема, имя вложений.
Вся эта масса событий существует в одной таблице Excel, хотя это не обязательно.
Отклонением может быть например такой случай: человек много пишет на адрес, с которого нет ответов. В теории - это может быть утечка через почту, которую не видит система контентного анализа.
Подскажите, были ли у кого кейсы по анализу почтового траффика (в разрезе UBA)?
Использовали ли Вы библиотеки Python для решения подобных задач? Если да то какие? Pandas, numpy?
Какие отклонения искали? И какой оказался результат?
Спасибо за Ваши комментарии!

Comment: А как вы определяете "адрес, с которого нет ответов"? На этот адрес пишут, а с этого адреса обратно не пишут, а у вас в логе и туда и обратно письма фиксируются? Вообще такие признаки очень сложно придумывать, это скорее искусство, чем наука.

Comment: "а у вас в логе и туда и обратно письма фиксируются?" - Да, и туда, и обратно. Придумать скрипты аномального поведения для меня не сложно. бОльшая сложность заключается в выборе математических методов и оценок моделей, представленных в Python. Ибо количество их широко, а опыт мой в Python узок :)

Comment: Ну, если вы можете придумать признаки, то проще всего, наверное, в `Pandas` данные крутить. Если эти признаки дают 100% результат, то это и всё. А вот если результат вероятностный, то дальше нужно копать в сторону машинного обучения и в частности задачи классификации, если вы можете разметить ваши данные - какого пользователя вы считаете отклонением, а какого нет. Но можно и без разметки. Есть методы выявления аномалий. Есть кластеризация. Тема очень большая. В общем, я бы рекомендовал в любом случае изучить `pandas` и `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Благодарю! Направление понятно!